# Parse database Multiple Images one Column

Tags: php

Is there a way to store multiple images in one column in Parse database? if so can you please give me a description of how and if not what would be a better way of going about storing multiple images that are related in Parse database.

Comment: what is "Parse" database, you mean MySQL? It's common recommendation to store files separately, not in DB. MySQL is not intended to store big array of files.

Comment: you can store the **image paths** in `array` and `serialize` that **array** and **_store_** `serialized value` in `mysql table`

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  No i do not mean MySql.  Parse is a database made by Facebook.  So this questions is regarding that particular case of how i would do that using the Parse.com database.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good way to store images in blob. However you can use another table with same column id and store multiple images.

Table 1:
Table1_id, column1, column2

Table 2:
Table2_id, table1_id, blob

In this way you can have multiple images and refer the first table.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to store multiple images in one column in Parse database.If you want to store multiple images in one column in that case you can use another table to store images after that save object id in a array type field of another table